# Add a new column and tag based on others with ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data set, I want to a new column using ifelse, see below.

```
mydat<-data.frame(DB=c("NO","NO","NO","NO",'YES','YES','YES','YES'),
                 DL =c("NO","NO","YES","YES",'NO','NO','YES','YES'))

mydat$NEW <- ifelse(mydat$DB=="YES", "DB",
                  ifelse(mydat$DL=="YES", "DL",
                         ifelse(mydat$DB=="YES" & mydat$DL=="YES","DBL", "NO")))
```

But the output is not the one I want

```
DB  DL NEW
  NO  NO  NO
  NO  NO  NO
  NO YES  DL
  NO YES  DL
  YES  NO  DB
  YES  NO  DB
  YES YES  DB
  YES YES  DB
```

Expected output is instead

```
  DB  DL NEW
  NO  NO  NO
  NO  NO  NO
  NO YES  DL
  NO YES  DL
  YES  NO  DB
  YES  NO  DB
  YES YES  DBL
  YES YES  DBL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `ifelse()` statements get unwieldy pretty quickly, give `dplyr::case_when()` a go:

```
data.frame(
  DB = c("NO","NO","NO","NO",'YES','YES','YES','YES'),
  DL = c("NO","NO","YES","YES",'NO','NO','YES','YES')
) -> mydat

dplyr::mutate(
  mydat, NEW = dplyr::case_when(
    ((DB == "YES") & (DL == "YES")) ~ "DBL",
    DB == "YES" ~ "DB",
    DL == "YES" ~ "DL",
    TRUE ~ "NO"
  )
)
##    DB  DL NEW
## 1  NO  NO  NO
## 2  NO  NO  NO
## 3  NO YES  DL
## 4  NO YES  DL
## 5 YES  NO  DB
## 6 YES  NO  DB
## 7 YES YES DBL
## 8 YES YES DBL
```

If you'd rather stick with base R, just reorder your conditions:

```
with(
  mydat,
  ifelse(
    ((DB == "YES") & (DL == "YES")), "DBL",
    ifelse(
      (DB == "YES"), "DB",
      ifelse(
        (DL == "YES"), "DL", "NO"
      )
    )
  )
) -> mydat$NEW
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mydat$NEW <-    
c("NO","DL","DB","DBL")[apply(mydat, 1 , function(x) sum(x == "YES") + (x[1] == "YES") + 1)]

#   DB  DL NEW
#1  NO  NO  NO
#2  NO  NO  NO
#3  NO YES  DL
#4  NO YES  DL
#5 YES  NO  DB
#6 YES  NO  DB
#7 YES YES DBL
#8 YES YES DBL
```

Comment: While this should likely never be used in production code, it is — nonetheless — a very clever hack :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want know why it's not working, it's caused by the logical path.

In the last condition

```
ifelse(mydat$DB=="YES" & mydat$DL=="YES","DBL", "NO")
```

you only enter if

```
 mydat$DL=="YES"
```

is FALSE, so this condition never applies.

if you want to do it with nested if_elses try:

```
mydat$NEW <- ifelse(mydat$DB=="YES"  & mydat$DL=="YES","DBL", 
                  ifelse(mydat$DL=="YES", "DL",
                         ifelse(mydat$DB=="YES","DB", "NO")))
```

In addition, you could prefer *dplyr* if_else, cause is safer and a good practice.

Comment: Multiple nested `dplyr::if_else()` statements are _just as bad_ as nested `ifelse()` statements. And, my answer covered everything in yours including the note to reorder the test conditions.